# Interpolate data to lat/lon grid in Python

Tags: python, interpolation, matplotlib-basemap

I am having trouble coming up with the most efficient way to convert satellite data on a non-regular grid to a global 0.25 x 0.25 deg grid.

I have a 2D array of satellite data, and two corresponding 2D arrays giving the latitude and longitude of each pixel.

When I plot it up using pcolormesh, it looks like this:

```
m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, windSpeed)
```

[image]

I want to interpolate this data onto 0.25 x 0.25 deg grid

```
lonGrid = arange(-180, 180, res)
latGrid = arange(-90, 90, res)
lonGrid,latGrid = meshgrid(lonGrid,latGrid)
```

I've tried messing around with the mpl_toolkits.basemap.interp() function, but I can't figure out how to get my lat and lon points to me monotonically increasing, which is required by the function. I can ravel() my lon grid, sort it to be increasing, and then sort the windSpeed and lat grids in the same way using argsort...but then lat isn't monotonically increasing.

```
lon = lon.ravel()
lat = lat.ravel()
windSpeed = windSpeed.ravel()

lon[lon > 180] = lon[lon > 180] - 360

lonSortInds = argsort(lon)

result = mpl_toolkits.basemap.interp(windSpeed2, lon2, lat2, lonGrid, latGrid, checkbounds=False, masked=True, order=1)

lat = lat[lonSortInds]
windSpeed = windSpeed[lonSortInds]

lon = sort(lon)

result = mpl_toolkits.basemap.interp(windSpeed, lon, lat, lonGrid, latGrid, checkbounds=False, masked=False, order=1)
```

> ValueError: xin and yin must be increasing!

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar error I have just had, I fixed it by doing a different type of re-order.

If your latitudes are not increasing you can try:

`np.flipud(lat)
np.flipud(windSpeed)`

or if it's longitudes that are not increasing then:

`np.fliplr(lon)
np.fliplr(windSpeed)`

This solved a similar issue I was having.